# Repartition and reinstall on 2012 Air + Mavericks

Tags: bootcamp, partition

I have an old macbook air (2012 edition), with BootCamp set up, with Windows 7 and Mavericks installed.

I want to wipe everything, all the data on both partitions, safely, and reinstall with a different partition size.

What's the best process for this? Reinstall Mavericks, then resize the partition? Resize, then reinstall Mavericks?

I'd appreciate any advice :)

Comment: There's many tutorials and sites around the net with the steps you need to follow to wipe your drive.  What have you already tried and what errors have you encountered?

Comment: A lot of the tutorials I've found are from many years ago and I'm not sure if something has changed, and I'm worried that I'll end up in a "bricked" state somehow if I do something in the wrong order.

Comment: There's a potential alternative, quicker & without needing to wipe & start from scratch - [Paragon Hard Disk Manager](https://www.paragon-software.com/home/hdm-mac/). It's not a procedure I've used myself [moving the partition boundaries between bootcamp/OS X], but I've used the app for other restructures, so far without incident. Backups always recommended, of course ;)

Answer (score 1):

The safest way to wipe your entire drive and do a clean OS install is this:

1. Remember to back up ALL of your data!
2. Open Boot Camp Assistant and select the "remove windows" option. Follow the steps to remove windows and resize your drive to only be MacOS.
3. After this is complete, shut down your computer.
4. Boot into recovery mode by holding `Cmd` + `R` at startup.
5. Open Disk Utility in recovery mode. Select the remaining partition (MacOS), then set a name for it in the box provided and wipe it.
6. After this is complete, close Disk Utility and choose the "Install Mac OS X" option.
7. Follow the steps to install Mac OS X on the new partition.